# Third party JavaScript - good idea to use try catch?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a third party JavaScript widget that will be included by users on their applications/blogs. I have good tests around the library, but I am afraid that if despite that if some syntax error sneaks through and cause the other scripts on the user's application to stop loading.

So - to prevent this from happening, is it a good idea to surround my entire widget code in a try/catch like this?

```
try {
    // my library
} catch(e) {
    // notify me about the error
}
```

Comment: One thing to think about.  If you're notified of the error, will you be passing that knowledge on to your users/callers?  (They might also be interested to know something failed)

Comment: How does a syntax error sneak through? You check your code before publishing, and if it doesn't have syntax errors, then it doesn't have syntax errors.

Comment: He probably means unfound bugs.

Comment: When you say `// notify me about the error` do you mean the user who is consuming your library or you as in the person who wrote the library?

Comment: @Vidas: Sneak through meaning - sometimes IE will just throw fits for an obscure thing. I can't possibly test on all devices. My concern is that if at all something breaks, it should be confined to my code, and this error should not cause other scripts on the page from to stop executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good common approach to what `try-catch` blocks are used for. If you can catch an exception and do something with that exception then go ahead and catch it. For example, `BadHtmlException` or something similar is an exception you can catch to provide user with feedback that you should fix the HTML and try again.

There are types of exceptions that there is no action that can be done. For example, the application was configured incorrectly with a bad user/password. This should be a critical error and should be push all the way up to the application. Possibly an exception that might not make sense to the user.

So what am I suggesting? I am suggesting don't wrap anything in a `try-catch` unless you know there will be that exception thrown. If there is a bug or exception, the person using your code should see it and report it as an issue. You really can't spend all your time going through possible issues that may or may not be your code.

Finally, you should write unit tests and make sure each part of your library is well tested before each release. Doing this will make sure that future releases don't break anything.

Comment: I don't think that submitting an invalid username should throw an exception. It's just a state - you can expect the user to make a typo occasionally. Exceptions are for unexpected behavior...

Comment: I didn't mean submitting an invalid username. I mean if the database was setup with the wrong credentials to begin with. As in, MySQL user/password. Nothing to do with user input. I will make my answer more clear.

Comment: More than catching the bug, I don't want exceptions from my script to break other scripts on the page.

Comment: I would argue that is something that should break the page. You want the user to see there is a problem and if you eat up the exception then he/she wouldn't know if things are working like they should be.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is have a try/catch block around the code, putting a console.log() call in the catch block. This way, consumer's code will still run, but when debugging, they'll see that something went wrong within your library and notify you.